# How to change the value in the array according to the index in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to change the value in the array according to the index in react hooks？
Is there any elegant solution？

```
export function Test() {
    const a =new Array(5).fill(0)
    console.log(a[0])
    const [data, setData] = useState(a);
    return <div>
{data.map(it=>(


<div onClick={


How do I make data[2]=1?



        ()=>setData(?)
    }>
        i am test {it}
</div>
))
}

</div>
}
```

Comment: `onClick={() => setData(oldData => { const newData = [...oldData]; newData[index] = newValue; return newData; })}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to re-render, just clone old array and set again

```
<div onClick={()=>{
   data[2] = 1;
   setData([...data])// clone old object
}>
        i am test {it}
</div>
```